# How many dimensions does a circle have?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, circles

Is a circle just a line (therefore 1 dimension) or is it a 2-dimensional object because it occupies some surface?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Åre you mixing the circle (1d) with the disk (2d)?

Comment: Expanding on the previous comment: mathematicians (when they're being careful) use the word "circle" for what you might call the circumference, and the word "disk" for the filled-in circle. Non-mathematicians use the word "circle" for both concepts. So if your question is about terminology, rather than mathematics, the answer is, 1-dimensional if a mathematician is involved, depends on context if not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A circle is a one-dimensional object, although one can *embed* it into a two-dimensional object. More precisely, it is a one-dimensional [manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold). Manifolds admit an abstract description which is independent of a choice of embedding: for example, if you believe string theorists, there is a $10$- or $11$- or $26$-dimensional manifold that describes spacetime and a few extra dimensions, and we can study this manifold without embedding it into some larger $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Incidentally, you might guess that $n$-dimensional things ought to be embeddable into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ ($n+1$-dimensional space). Actually, this is false: there are intrinsically $n$-dimensional things, such as the [Klein bottle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle) (which is $2$-dimensional) which can't be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. The Klein bottle does admit an embedding into $\mathbb{R}^4$. More generally, the [Whitney embedding theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem) tells you that [smooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold) $n$-dimensional manifolds can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ for $n > 0$, and for topological manifolds see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34658/is-there-a-whitney-embedding-theorem-for-non-smooth-manifolds).

There are also other notions of dimension more general than that for manifolds: see [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension#Manifolds).